# Read entire physical memory using kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I have to write a kernel module which iterates over all pages of the physical memory and compute hash over contents of each page.
I know basics of kernel module. Can someone give me overview to how should I proceed.

Till now, I have iterated over all the physical pages but I am not able to figure out how to read content of page given physical address of page (or given page struct).

Comment: you can do it via void *kmap(struct page *page); By the way, why do you want to do this?

Comment: These hashes will be used to look for the possibility of content based sharing between various VMs. If two VMs on different hosts have most of the content same(found by comparing hashes) then they both will be moved to same host, hence saving resources.

Comment: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1 pretty clean explanation

Comment: @AlexHoppus void *kmap(struct page *page) worked fine. Thanks.